# Using jQuery to get data attributes

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Now, bear in mind I'm just trying to ensure that the code works by consuming the `ready` event here. I just want to make sure that the data I expect is getting pulled by jQuery. I've also tried the `load` event.

In the end I'd want to use the `load` or `ready` event to set the image initially and then of course use the `hover` event to change that image on hover.

I've tried a lot of the answers here on SO and just can't seem to get this working, so hopefully y'all can help me.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submenumain-link").ready(function () {
        alert($(this).data()["selectedimage"]);
        alert($(this).data()["hoverimage"]);
    });

    $("#submenumain-link").hover(function () {
        alert($(this).data("selectedimage"));
        alert($(this).data("hoverimage"));
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<li id="submenumain-link"
    data-selectedimage="some-image.png"
    data-hoverimage="some-other-image.png">
```

But for whatever reason the `alert` messages just state undefined. Am I missing something here?

### EDIT

Note that if I place those same `alert` statements in the hover, it works as expected. What event could I use to do the initialization?

Comment: I understand it's weird that this isn't working, but why are you using `.ready`? I'm surprised it's working, because you're binding the `ready` event for the `li` after the DOM is ready (`document.ready`), so I don't even know why it's firing - it's already ready!

Comment: I don't think you need to bind a `ready` event...just check immediately inside of `document.ready`, since the `li` is "ready" at that point.

Comment: @ianpgall, good point! Should I just place that outside in the `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Yeah, at that time, it should be ready. I think `ready` is really only used for `document` - http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @ianpgall, okay so it at least netted the same result in the `$(document).ready`, but it's still not pulling the value.

Comment: Did you use `this` still? `this` should refer to `document`, not the `li` in `document.ready`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is that `ready` should not be used in this way. The `ready` event should only be used with making sure the DOM is ready - http://api.jquery.com/ready/

So technically, inside of `document.ready`, all of the DOM is ready and should be available for these kinds of things. Inside of `document.ready`, the value of `this` refers to the `document` element, so you need to actually grab the `li` element. Your code should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var li = $("#submenumain-link");
    alert(li.data()["selectedimage"]);  // or li.data("selectedimage")

    li.hover(function () {
        //alert($(this).data("selectedimage"));
        //alert($(this).data("hoverimage"));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XN2LV/

Answer (score 5):

```
$(this).data('selectedimage');
```

You don't need the brackets []

Comment: Yeah, I hate this, but this yielded `undefined` in the alert as well. I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: maybe do a fiddle?  I use this exact scenario too many times to count in a couple web apps without issue.

Comment: Check your version of jQuery, this was added in 1.4.3, http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: This won't fix anything. Calling `.data` returns the full object of data items associated with the element. This is no different than what the OP already has: http://jsfiddle.net/5cRdQ/

Comment: Please see my edit, it apparently works in the `hover` event. Also, I'm using the absolute latest build of jQuery, I downloaded it from NuGet.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is your .ready() call.  You should use a [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) if you want to wait until something is loaded but in this case it is an li element that will already exist so your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test = $("#submenumain-link");
    alert(test.data('selectedimage'));
    alert(test.data('hoverimage'));

    test.hover(function() {});
});
```

Comment: This won't fix anything. Calling `.data` returns the full object of data items associated with the element. This is no different than what the OP already has: http://jsfiddle.net/5cRdQ/

Comment: Good point, that was a good distractor, updated to reflect the real issue

Comment: And you can't use the `load` event on an `li` element, look at the link you provided...it says: "This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object."

Comment: Right, that's what I was saying, in this case an li has nothing to load, it is instantly there so to speak.  The OP mentioned the end goal is loading an image...so I gave them the info they would need to do that eventually.  This example can't because it's just a DOM element as you correctly pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `alert($(this).data("selectedimage"));`

Look here: [HTML5 data-* Attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5).

Comment: This won't fix anything. Calling `.data` returns the full object of data items associated with the element. This is no different than what the OP already has: http://jsfiddle.net/5cRdQ/